# wifi connected but no internet access in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet

This cannot be a duplicate question. I tried most of the options from stack-overflow & askubuntu but couldn't get the solution. I upgraded to 16.04.01 recently. Last week my Internet was working fine but this week, wifi is connected but there is no Internet connection. I cannot open any websites. I have windows 10 in which I have no issue connecting to the Internet. Please help.

Comment: what do you see when you run `ifconfig` in the terminal? what are the addresses assigned to the wifi adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your terminal : `ping www.google.com`

When you will press enter, it will start pinging Google and a long stream of text will be visible in the terminal. If after pressing enter this message is displayed "Host not found". Then maybe your WiFi driver isn't compatible with Ubuntu 16.04. Either move to 14.04 or run 16.04 using a live USB and then try to connect and browse the Internet. If it connects and Internet works fine in Live USB, then reinstall Ubuntu.

I also faced this problem but when I booted using Live USB, the problem was solved.

Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: i tried installing ubuntu 14.04 and still having the same problem. wifi icon shows it connected but no internet.